# Why does running `gcloud run deploy`, exactly according to the tutorial, give the error "image must be specified"

Tags: python, docker, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I'm following the Google Cloud Run quickstart for Python, but it ain't working. I am running Python 3.7, have `gcloud` installed, and have all the necessary permissions on my project.

Here's the tutorial I followed: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service

Here's evidence I copied their four files into the right place locally:

```
******@penguin:~/helloworld$ ls -a
.  ..  Dockerfile  .dockerignore  main.py  requirements.txt
```

And yet here's what I see when I run the final command, `gcloud run deploy`:

```
******@penguin:~/helloworld$ gcloud run deploy
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) argument --image: Must be specified.
```

According to the error, I need to specify an image (presumably existing), yet the tutorial is explicit that running this command from the source directory will automatically build an image. Here's their line: "Deploy from source automatically builds a container image from source code and deploys it."

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Can you share the result of the command: gcloud config list?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere:
`****@penguin:~/helloworld$ gcloud config list
[core]
account = tim@dcyd.io
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = daas-316706

Your active configuration is: [demos]`

Comment: What's your GCLOUD version? perform a `gcloud version` to know it and share it

Comment: `******@penguin:~/helloworld$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 317.0.0
alpha 2020.10.30
beta 2020.10.30
bq 2.0.62
core 2020.10.30
gsutil 4.54
kubectl 1.16.13`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing you are in the folder where the files are, you can create a docker image:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/your_project_id/image_name .
```

Then

```
gcloud run deploy service-name --image gcr.io/your_project_id/image_name
```

Comment: Thank you! Works.

Comment: As usual, StackOverflow succeeds where Google documentation fails miserably

Answer (score 2):

Ok, update your gcloud SDK. the Current version is 379, you are 62 versions behind, more than 1 year, and 1year ago, the `gcloud run deploy`  to upload sources, build a container and deploy it on Cloud Run didn't exist

Comment: Thanks, Guillaume. (btw, your comment is a bit garbled.)
* Ran `gcloud components update` ==> now at version 334.0.0
* `gcloud run deploy` gets farther, but not to the end. After some menus, am asked for a service name (which is supposed to have a default value according to some docs). After entering a name, I still get `ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Missing required argument [--image]: Requires a container image to deploy (e.g. `gcr.io/cloudrun/hello:latest`) if no build source is provided.` But I provided, source, following the tutorial, so this still makes no sense.... :(

Comment: Guillaume, thanks for your articles introducing me to Cloud Run (e.g. https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-cloud-function-what-i-use-and-why-12bb5d3798e1).

It's odd that your solution, which ought to be the correct one—given it's what Google says to do, is not working....

Comment: You must use the 354 version or above. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#cloud_run_10